# what does as many as (two hundred pizza) mean?

Tags: meaning, expressions

I read an article saying:

> I delivered as many as two hundred pizzas!

Is this correct? What does it mean, as many as two? Is is similar to *about*, *maximum*, or *almost*?

Comment: there's nothing wrong with "as many as", as answered already; the plural form of "pizza" is "pizzas" though (or "pizze", if you want to use the Italian) - so the correct sentence would be "I delivered as many as two hundred pizzas!"

Comment: "As many as two" can be used rather ironically. In its literal sense, two isn't a big number, is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence you saw in the article is correct. It means: *I am surprised that I delivered such a big number of pizzas.*

It isn't similar to **about** (= approximately, give or take a few items) or **almost** (= nearly) or **maximum** (= the most possible/allowed).

Comment: The maximum means that you have a upper limit so it is not correct to use it in that context (x=<1000). I agree about the others. Generally it means more or less the number. In math we would say that x is closed in [1000-e,1000+e] interval, where e is really a small number.

Comment: what if I get a `as many as two`? Isn't two too small for such an expression?

Comment: Wouldn't it be 'two hundred pizzas'?

Comment: Or "two hundred pizzae"?

Comment: @BarrieEngland: My mistake. I should have written 'pizzas'.

Comment: @JeffSahol: I've never seen this form.

Comment: @JeffSahol: 'Pizze', I believe.

Comment: @Irene It's the first declension nominative plural in Latin (or first declension genitive or dative singular).  Of course, `pizza` comes from Italian and not Latin, and for Italian nouns ending in `-a` the plural takes an ending of `-e` in place of the `-a`, so as Barrie said, should be `Pizze`.  Unless the `a` is accented in Italian.